# PHP classes and functions

Tags: php, function, class

In PHP I have 3 separate classes all doing totally different tasks. However a number of functions are shared between two or all three classes.

- Class `search`
- Class `data_table`
- Class `add_and_edit`

All three classes have a function that corrects for Scottish and Irish names (Mac Mc O' etc), two classes share a letter header function and a different two classes share a third function.

Is it possible to lump the shared functions into one file and call them with a class when needed?

Comment: We could give you better answer if you gave us some code, representing the usage of shared functions in your classes. There are 2 basic methods: create a parent class and put the functions to a separate file.

Comment: What would be the problem of having these functions inside another class (maybe as static)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have spent a few hours on this. The common functions (format names etc) I want to keep in one place to help with editing and updating. However after reading kingoero and Clamidity replies it just became clear. I need to put the common functions in a PARENT class and EXTEND that with the search, data_table classes. NOT the other way around! What a plonker I am. Many thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think will better use `base` class for hold your general functions and extend it in other classes. General function must be defined `protected`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an inheritance structure.

Exmaple:

```
class meta{
   protected function add(args){
   }
   protected function edit(args){
   }
   protected function delete(args){
   }

}
/*@description This class get all the 3 methods from the meta class*/
class search extends meta{

}
 /*@description This class get all the 3 methods from the meta class*/    
class data_table extends meta{
}
/*@description This class get all the 3 methods from the meta class*/    
class add_and_edit extends meta{
}
```

Use a protected functions to conceal functions from the public API(disable calling those functions from outside the class), but still keep the ability for inheriting(child) classes to get those functions by inheritance.

Comment: This is true and also helpful, but doesn't necessarily follow separation of concerns. It would probably be better to have a service that can be injected.

Comment: Those are architecture concerns, and the guy is obviously still at the beginning of the road, thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would be the logical solution here. I would create a parent class, cay called 'parent', then extend the other classes:

```
class child extends parent {}
```

Move the common methods to the parent class. Then each class will still have access to these common methods, and you code should work as it did before, unless you are making static method calls.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1: Inheritance

Your question is very unspecific which will be reflected in my answer. I think what you're looking for is inheritance.

Inheritance allows you you have a class with a function and then have other classes *inherit* those functions.

```
class A {
  public function x();
}

class B extends A {
  public function y();
}
```

Now your class B will have both the method x() and y(). You can even nest this further, e.g.

```
class C extends B {
  public function z()
}
```

So that C now has all of x(), y(), and z(). Additionally, you can have a class inherit from multiple classes. Be careful with inheritance, though, you can end up with complicated class hierarchies, tight couplings, and an awful lot of dependecies.

### Solution 2: Static classes

You could separate your name-correction functions from your other classes and store them in a static class and call that from whereever you need, e.g.

```
class A {
  public static function nameThingy() {
    // ...
  }
}
class B {
  public function something() {
    A::nameThingy();
  }
}
class C {
  public function somethingElse() {
    A::nameThingy();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a controller class and have each of the three classes [extend](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php) off the controller.

```
<?php 
class app_controller {
    public static function name_correction( $name ) {
        // process
        return $fixed_name;
    }
} 

class search extends app_controller  {
    // ...

    private function action() { 
        // code ...
        $do_something = self::name_correction( $name );
        // code 
   } 
}
class data_table extends app_controller  {
    // ...

    private function another_action() { 
        // code ...
        $do_something = self::name_correction( $name );
        // code 
   } 
} 
class add_and_edit extends app_controller  {
    // ...

    private function another_action() { 
        // code ...
        $do_something = self::name_correction( $name );
        // code 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Why do you use static functions?

Comment: @OlegTikhonov because the class isn't instantiated and the function is just associated.

Comment: How do you know that the behavior of those function is not instance specific?

Comment: @OlegTikhonov Well, I don't necessarily know for sure but based on the question he made me think it wasn't, since he's calling inside the class common functions. Regardless, if he calls the function statically the value is valid. What do you see wrong with this method?

Comment: Nothing, except perhaps you should add an explanation of what is a static method, and what is it used for, also that is accessed in the class context, and not in the instance context with self:: instead of $this->